# In Android studio gradle can I use Robolectric and Android instrumentation at the same time?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

In Android studio gradle can I use Robolectric and Android instrumentation at the same time?

Can anyone tell me on how to do this stuff? To have a test project for robolectric and Android instrumentation at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to achieve this setup. The most popular is reported by robolectric guys. But I dislike their solution, because of dependency pollution. For details read following post: [Android project with Robolectric and Gradle (Android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800238/android-project-with-robolectric-and-gradle-android-studio/23557531#23557531)

Answer (score 0):

I've got both tests running in one project.

Execute the Robolectrics tests with `gradle test`

Execute the Espresso tests with `gradle connectedCheck`

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    // tell Android studio that the instrumentTest source set is located in the unit test source set
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
}

androidTest {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/*/*.class'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```