# Android Instrumented Tests coverage exclude flies

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, instrumentation

I run my tests with "gradlew createDebugCoverageReport". My problem is that the coverage report includes every single source file I have. I want to exclude some files. I added this to my build.gradle but it did not work:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java
                {
                    exclude '**/TouchImageView.java'
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800238/android-project-with-robolectric-and-gradle-android-studio, look he doesn't use java {}

Comment: If I do it this way I get the following error "Gradle DSL method not found: 'androidTest()'"

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the jacoco plugin at the begining of your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

Then enable the coverage with `testCoverageEnabled true` i.e

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
```

And create the task `jacocoTestReport`:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "connectedDebugAndroidTest") {

    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    // exclude auto-generated classes and tests
    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class',
                      '**/R$*.class',
                      '**/BuildConfig.*',
                      '**/Manifest*.*',
                      '**/*IScript*.*',
                      'android/**/*.*',
                      '**/*_Factory*',
                      '**/*_MembersInjector*',
                      '**/*Fake*']

    def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
            "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug",
            excludes: fileFilter)

    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])

    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes:
            ['**/*.exec', '**/*.ec'])

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.destination = "${buildDir}/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        csv.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination = "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
    }
}
```

Add your exclusions to `fileFilter` array.
Then run the report:

```
$ gradle jacocoTestReport
```