# Exclude packages from `createDebugCoverageReport` task

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, instrumentation

I'm trying to exclude packages when running the `createDebugCoverageReport` task, but with no success. I've tried solutions like these:

- https://medium.com/@snmaddula/configuring-jacoco-in-a-gradle-project-af144fb9364a
- [Android Instrumented Tests coverage exclude flies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886647/android-instrumented-tests-coverage-exclude-flies)
- https://medium.com/@korwin22/jacoco-for-android-e56bffedef48

And I've tried to edit the task itself where there is a option to exclude packages from coverage data:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `excludes` didn't work, so I fixed with `includes`. Here is the code, it will combine unit tests and instrumented tests in a single coverage report.

```
task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        csv.enabled = true
    }

    def includeFiles = [
            '**/database/**/*.*',
            '**/repository/**/*.*',
            '**/network/worker/*.*',
            '**/util/extensions/*.*'
    ]

    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    classDirectories.from =
            fileTree(
                    dir: "$buildDir/intermediates/app_classes/debug",
                    includes: includeFiles
            ) + fileTree(
                    dir: "$buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
                    includes: includeFiles
            )
    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    executionData.from =
            fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
                    "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                    "outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*coverage.ec"
            ])
}
```