# Gradle Android unit tests that depend on an 'aar'

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

Want to be able to depend on an AAR for my unit tests in a Gradle-Android project.  I do not want to manually include the external library source or binaries inside my project (for multiple reasons).

We can depend on remote aar files like this in the build.gradle:

`compile 'com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk:3.6.0:@aar'`

But when using the gradle test method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16952507/821636 (Since [Jake Wharton's plugin](https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin),  isn't quite there yet), trying to include an aar as a dependency for that method like this:

`testLocalCompile 'com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk:3.6.0:@aar`

Does not seem to actually include the aar in the classpath for tests (run with `./gradlew check`) since I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for classes in the aar.  NOTE: When jar dependencies are included this way, they work.

Thinking there must be something in that `localTest` task that needs to add the aar extension since it's not the default type of dependency (jar).

Here is copy of that task copied from the SO answer referenced above:

```
task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assembleDebug) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir
    workingDir = "${rootProject.projectDir}/app/src/main"

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')

        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')
        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem and found a solution - include the classes.jar from the exploded bundle (.aar) in the build folder. I don't think will help with finding resources in .aar dependencies though.

```
testLocalCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/exploded-bundles", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

**Edit:** Since Android Gradle build tools **0.9.0** the dependency has changed to:

```
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/exploded-aar", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

As of Android Gradle plugin **0.12.2**:

```
testLocalCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar/", include:"**/classes.jar")
```

Comment: Yeah, assumed I could manually extract the lib and include that way, but then I'm doing the thing that dependency management through a build file is supposed to take care of.  Good to know there is a way to hack it if need-be (but then resources...) Looks like the android-gradle-aar ecosystem just isn't there yet.

Comment: I used this line, essentially, as also referenced in this similar question to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24954215/821636  'unitTestCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar/", include:"**/classes.jar")
' as of Android Gradle plugin 0.12.2. Will mark this as accepted since it has evolved into the answer that works the best so far.

Comment: Any luck modifying this method to work with flavors?  When I add flavors, the testLocal fails not being able to find _any_ of my classes.