# Gradle Android unit tests that depend on an 'aar' for build tool 0.11.+

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I am using gradle build system to run Roboletric tests however I've encountered the problem that was described here [Gradle Android unit tests that depend on an 'aar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099754/gradle-android-unit-tests-that-depend-on-an-aar) but the solution only works for build tool version 0.9.+ and not 0.11.+
as I cannot find the exploded-aar directory. Any ideas?

Here's the partial build file

```
configurations {
    testLocalCompile {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}

sourceSets {
    testLocal {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/res')
        compileClasspath += configurations.testLocalCompile
        runtimeClasspath += compileClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
testLocalCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar", include: "**/classes.jar")

}

task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'intermediates', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')

        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn localTest
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? Also are you running test in AS or from console?

Comment: I'm running from the console, but I do not see the exploded-aar directory

Comment: It should be noted that from the first post about the "localTest" unit test hack on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16952507/821636), notice the addition of "intermediates" in the buildDir creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it: it seems like in the 0.11.+ build tool the exploded-aar folder is moved to root. I had to change the dependency:

```
testLocalCompile fileTree(dir: "${rootDir}/build/exploded-aar", include: "**/classes.jar")
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you playing with folders. Here is mine gradle file (https://github.com/emartynov/UrlSetter/blob/master/build.gradle)

Answer (score 4):

That change again in **0.12.2**

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

> Move unzipped aar back in each project as a temporary fix for a possible race condition.

So you have to change the dependency back:

> ```
> unitTestCompile fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar/", include:"**/classes.jar")
> ```

(PS: do not know if is it the right way to post this in stackoverflow)